# Logic and geometry problem 2

Tags: logical-deduction, board-games

My question is whether or not a deadlock can occur in Crisscross.  A deadlock is defined as a position, an arrangement of checkers, in which the board has been filled but neither player has won.

[Crisscross](https://www.marksteeregames.com/Crisscross_rules.pdf)

[image: Crisscross]

Please either find a legal series of placements which leads to a deadlock, or formulate a proof that a deadlock can never happen.

Incidentally, I would like to thank Retudin for solving the last puzzle I posted.  This lead to a revision of the rules of Clearcut which make the game finite.

[Clearcut](https://www.marksteeregames.com/Clearcut_rules.pdf)

[image: Clearcut]

Comment: When and where will your game be released? Sounds fun

Comment: Clearcut is played at Abstract Play

Comment: https://play.abstractplay.com/

Comment: There's also a discussion forum for Abstract Play

https://discord.gg/ScPfaAyaWJ

...as well as my discussion forum

https://discord.gg/feCAeKxyxD

Comment: You've done a great job of avoiding gendered pronouns in your rules (thank you!) but I did notice one "his" in the discussion of Figure 4 of Clearcut.

Comment: I make no attempt to avoid gendered pronouns.  I'm 64 and "in my day," in something like a rule sheet for a game, which is clearly meant to be played by all genders, "his" was a shorthand convenience for "his or hers."  Then also, the problem with "they" is that it's plural.  The task in writing a rule sheet is to minimize ambiguity and avoid confusion.  Using a plural pronoun for something that has to be singular doesn't help, at all.  So, while I'm sympathetic to genders, and don't wish to offend anyone, this is how I do it.